# (SOLVED) MAUI Slow/Laggy Scrolling in ListView and CollectionView

Tags: android, xaml, listview, collectionview, maui

**EDIT:**

I found the culprit. Namely me ^^

In my Rectangle in the ListView I gave it a HeightRequest of -1, which led to it being constantly rendered. *Note never set Width-,HeightRequest to -1 in a view.

---

Hey Guys First iam a **XAML Rookie**, i came from WinForms and using MAUI now since about 1 Month.

I would be very happy if someone could look over the code for me, it could be that I may have not followed an important order, which is why the performance is suffering so extremely.

I have some issues with my ListView, its very Laggy and scrolling from 1 item to the next take 1-2 seconds sometimes.
I Debug and Release with inBuild Debugger and my own Dev Phone too (Samsung A13 2022).

Also i read something about a bigger performance improvement with a CollectionView instead of ListView but i have exact the same Result.

Maybe i have some mistakes made and here is someone there can explain me what it is.

My ListView is filled with Data from a ViewModel.

Here my XAML:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="DocuWeb.Termine"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DocuWeb"
             xmlns:syncfusion="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.Maui.ListView;assembly=Syncfusion.Maui.ListView"
             xmlns:data="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.Maui.DataSource;assembly=Syncfusion.Maui.DataSource"
             Title="Terminliste" 
             Background="#cccccc" >
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:ViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem 
        Order="Secondary" 
        Text="Service auf diesem Gerät"
        Priority="1"/>
        <ToolbarItem 
        Order="Secondary"
        Text="Objekte sichern/entfernen"
        Priority="2"/>
        <ToolbarItem 
        Order="Secondary"
        Text="Vertretung wählen"
        Priority="3"/>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <Grid RowDefinitions="30,*" ColumnDefinitions="Auto"  Margin="0" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Fill" RowSpacing="5">
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" RowDefinitions="40" WidthRequest="-1" Margin="0,15,0,0" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
            <Frame             
                Background="Ghostwhite"
                CornerRadius="8"
                Padding="5"
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" >
                <Border  
                    MaximumWidthRequest="372"
                    WidthRequest="372"
                    StrokeThickness="0"               
                    BackgroundColor="#a6a6a6"
                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"     
                    StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 8,8,8,8">
                    <SearchBar 
                        x:Name="SearchBar"
                        Placeholder="Kunde suchen..."
                        x:FieldModifier="Public"
                        PlaceholderColor="GhostWhite"
                        FontSize="15"
                        TextChanged="OnFilterTextChanged"        
                        TextColor="GhostWhite"
                        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                    </SearchBar>
                </Border>
            </Frame>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1"  Margin="0,10,0,0"  >
            <Border x:Name="Border"
                    x:FieldModifier="public"
                    StrokeThickness="0"
                    Background="Transparent"
                    Margin="0,0,1.5,0"
                    InputTransparent="false"
                    StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 8,8,8,8"
                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start">
                <Border.Shadow>
                    <Shadow 
                        Brush="#4B39EF"
                        Radius="18"
                        Opacity="0.7"/>
                </Border.Shadow>
                <syncfusion:SfListView     
                    x:Name="listView"
                    AutoFitMode="DynamicHeight"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Firmen}"
                    SelectionMode="Single"
                    Background="Transparent"             
                    Grid.Row="1"              
                    Grid.Column="1" 
                    ItemSpacing="2.5"
                    x:FieldModifier="public"
                    PropertyChanged="listView_PropertyChanged"
                    SelectionGesture="Tap"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding listViewItem}"
                    SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding listView_SelectionChangedCommand}"
                    SelectionBackground="#6857ff">
                    <syncfusion:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate >
                            <Grid BackgroundColor="Transparent" Padding="5,-1,0,-1" ColumnSpacing="5" RowDefinitions="*" ColumnDefinitions="70,*">
                                <Border 
                                StrokeThickness="0"
                                StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 8,8,8,8">
                                    <Image     
                                        Source="{Binding Path=DayImageSource}"
                                        HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                                        VerticalOptions="Center" 
                                        HeightRequest="75" 
                                        WidthRequest="75" 
                                        Aspect="Fill"
                                       >

                                    </Image>
                                </Border>
                                <Border 
                                    Grid.Column="1"
                                    StrokeThickness="0"
                                    StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 8,0,8,0">
                                    <Grid BackgroundColor="#FFFFFF" Padding="5" RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto">

                                        <Label
                                            Text="{Binding Path=Firma}" 
                                            Margin="5,0,0,0"
                                            LineBreakMode="WordWrap" 
                                            TextColor="#4B39EF" 
                                            FontFamily="Roboto-Medium" 
                                            FontSize="15"
                                            FontAttributes="Bold"
                                           />
                                        <Rectangle  Grid.Row="1" Margin="5,0,5,0" Background="#F1F4F8" HeightRequest="-1" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                                        <Label 
                                            Grid.Row="2" 
                                            LineBreakMode="NoWrap" 
                                            Margin="5,7,5,0" 
                                            TextColor="#95A1AC" 
                                            LineHeight="1.1" 
                                            FontAttributes="Bold"
                                            Text="{Binding Path=Termin}" 
                                            FontFamily="Roboto-Regular" 
                                            FontSize="13" />
                                        <Image 
                                            Grid.Row="3" 
                                            Margin="5,5,0,0" 
                                            Source="location.png" 
                                            HorizontalOptions="Start" 
                                            HeightRequest="18" 
                                            Aspect="AspectFit"/>
                                        <Label 
                                            Grid.Row="3" 
                                            LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" 
                                            Margin="30,5,0,0" 
                                            TextColor="#4B39EF" 
                                            FontAttributes="Bold,Italic"
                                           
                                            VerticalOptions="Center"
                                            HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                         
                                            FontFamily="Roboto-Regular" 
                                            FontSize="13" >
                                            <Label.Text>
                                                <MultiBinding StringFormat="DE-{0} {1}, {2}">
                                                    <Binding Path="Postleitzahl" />
                                                    <Binding Path="Ort" />
                                                    <Binding Path="Strasse" />
                                                </MultiBinding>
                                            </Label.Text>
                                        </Label>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Border>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </syncfusion:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
                </syncfusion:SfListView>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
        <ContentView  
            x:Name="ContentPanel" 
            Grid.Row="1"
            Content="{Binding bottomSheet}"
            VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"     
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
            Margin="0,-15" 
            Background="Transparent" />
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: you are using SFListView, not the standard ListView or CollectionView

Comment: Sure sorry i forgot to say. But this doesnt matter, i tried also the original ListView. I thought someone around my ListView makes this issues but there is only a Shadow effect which makes also with or without it, no difference :/

Comment: if you get poor performance with all three controls, I'd be more focused on the data

Comment: This comment get me to look inside my ListView.. it was the Rectangle... i think the Rectangle is reRendering each time i start to scroll. without the Rectangle its moving so smoothly now. This Rectangle works at my code as a Seperator in a list item. This should give the item Row a better looking. Sadly i should discard this idea now.. EDIT: NVM it was the HeightRequest. it was set to -1... Now it works. Thanks ^^

Comment: FYI: In the future, when you solve a problem, don't edit your question. Instead, add "Your Answer" below. This makes it clearer in the future which part is the "problem", which part is the "solution". Thanks. [StackOverflow is a different format than a forum, where you might go back and "edit the original post and title" to flag the fact that it has been solved.]